# INDY10 Stream write error while I trying to send data trought FTP

Tags: delphi, ftp, indy, indy10

I want to put data from Memo1 directly to my FTP server, I've got code:

```
procedure TForm5.SendClick(Sender: TObject);  
var K: TStream;  
begin  
    K := TStream.Create;
    Memo1.Lines.SaveToStream(K);
    FTP.Host := 'localhost';
    FTP.Username := 'login';
    FTP.Password := 'haslo';
    FTP.Connect;
    if FTP.Connected then FTP.Put(K,'');
end;
```

But when I click "Send" button I've got two errors:

[image]

when Memo is empty

[image]

when I try send data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TStream` is an abstract class. You must never instantiate it. Use a concrete class instead like, for instance, `TMemoryStream`.

You'll also want to destroy the stream when you are finished with it, or it will leak. Do yourself a favour and set `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown` to `True`, for instance in your .dpr file. That will allow you to get a report of all the memory you are leaking when your program terminates.

Your code might run like this:

```
var 
  Stream: TMemoryStream;  
....
Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
  // .... initialize the Indy object
  if FTP.Connected then begin
    // .... populate stream
    Stream.Position := 0;
    FTP.Put(Stream, '');
  end;
finally
  Stream.Free;    
end;
```